# Why do list / dictionary comprehensions have different scope within classes?

Tags: python, scope, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Executing this fails:

```
class Data:
    foo = 12
    bar = 42
    baz = [i * bar for i in range(foo)]
```

Executing this works:

```
foo = 12
bar = 42
baz = [i * bar for i in range(foo)]
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36161632/562769) which seems to be a more complicated version of essentially the same problem, but no clear answer to why the scope seems to change within a class + dict / list comprehension.